# Delete matching items of list

Tags: python, list

so i am trying to match the elements of out_list with the main_list second index values and if they match , i want to delete that certain label. Like in out list we have one label "sleeveless" so I want it deleted wherever it is in the 2nd index of main list. For example after eradication of matching words from out_list, the first list element for mainlist will be come:

```
['img/Sleeveless_Vented_Blouse/img_00000037.jpg', 'printed,chiffon,floral', '0']
```

This is what i have tried, i don't know how to go further

```
main_list=[ ['img/Sleeveless_Vented_Blouse/img_00000037.jpg', 'printed,sleeveless,chiffon,floral', '0'], ['img/Sleeveless_Vented_Blouse/img_00000038.jpg', 'printed,ruffle', '0'], ['img/Sleeveless_Vented_Blouse/img_00000040.jpg', 'sleeveless', '0'] ]
    out_list = ['collar', 'floralprint', 'longsleeve', 'pink', 'pintuck', 'red', 'shirt', 'sleeve', 'sleeveless', 'split', 'trim', 'tunic', 'v-neck']
    for i in range(main_list):
      att=m[i].split(",")
      for t in out_list:
      if t in att:
```

Below is a test dataset:

```
out_list = ['collar', 'floralprint', 'longsleeve', 'pink', 'pintuck', 'red', 'shirt', 'sleeve', 'sleeveless', 'split', 'trim', 'tunic', 'v-neck']
main_list=[['img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000001.jpg', 'pleated,sheer', '0'], ['img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000002.jpg', 'pleated,sheer', '0'], ['img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000009.jpg', 'sheer', '0'], ['img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000010.jpg', 'sheer,woven', '0'], ['img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000014.jpg', 'summer', '0'], ['img/Sleeveless_Vented_Blouse/img_00000037.jpg', 'printed,sleeveless,shirt,chiffon,floral', '0'], ['img/Sleeveless_Vented_Blouse/img_00000038.jpg', 'printed,ruffle', '0'], ['img/Sleeveless_Vented_Blouse/img_00000040.jpg', 'sleeveless', '0'] ]
```

Comment: your `out_list` is not a valid python object

Comment: If you're only matching unique elements and do not care how many times they appear, you should use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex built on `out_list`:

*NB. assuming `out_list = ['collar', 'floralprint', 'longsleeve', 'pink', 'pintuck', 'red', 'shirt', 'sleeve', 'sleeveless', 'split', 'trim', 'tunic', 'v-neck']`*

```
import re
regex = re.compile('(%s)' % '|'.join(sorted(out_list)[::-1]), flags=re.I)


filtered_main = [[l[0],
                  ','.join(i for i in l[1].split(',')
                           if i not in map(str.lower, regex.findall(l[0]))),
                  l[2]]
                 for l in main_list
                ]
```

output:

```
[['img/Sleeveless_Vented_Blouse/img_00000037.jpg', 'printed,chiffon,floral', '0'],
 ['img/Sleeveless_Vented_Blouse/img_00000038.jpg', 'printed,ruffle', '0'],
 ['img/Sleeveless_Vented_Blouse/img_00000040.jpg', '', '0']]
```

Comment: it does work with your solution but if i add more values to main list it doesn't work... like i just added one more item "['img/Sheer_Lace_&_Chiffon_Blouse/img_00000134.jpg', 'chiffon,floral,lace,longsleeve,sheer,','0']" and it gives the error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: @mozaway I think i have pinpointed the issue, it's the image link, since I have more records the image link differs and so does its length. This is why it doesn't work for others.

Comment: @SoulD82 can you provide an example?

Comment: @mozaway i have added it above in the question, please check.

Comment: @SoulD82 I see, if a match is not guaranteed, use `re.findall`, see my update

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the question well, but oh well, here we go:

Suppose we have elements of a list that look like 'img/Sleeveless_Vented_Blouse/img_00000037.jpg'. Provided that we need to remove all the elements of the list that contain 'Sleeveless', we can do it like this:

```
to_be_removed = 'Sleeveless'
for element in elements_list:
    if to_be_removed in element:
        elements_list.remove(element)


for check_word in check_list:
    for item in main_list:
        if check_word in item:
            main_list.remove(item)
```

Simply because:

```
>>> a = 'img/Sleeveless_Vented_Blouse/img_00000037.jpg'
>>> 'Sleeveless' in a
True
```

Hope I answered the right question.

Comment: Doesn't work sorry, it's a huge list of lists. As a standalone variable it does but not in my case :(

Comment: In that case make a nested for loop. Take a look at the edited answer. @SoulD82